# Creating Hive table on Parquet file which has JSON data

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hiveql, parquet

The objective I'm trying to achieve

1. Obtain the data from source big JSON files ( **employee-sample.json**)
2. A simple spark application to read it as text file and store in parquet ( **simple-loader.java** ). I'm not aware of what is in JSON file so I cannot put any schema , so I want schema on read, and not schema on write. A parquet file with one column named "value" containing the JSON string in created
3. Create an HIVE external table on parquet files, and when I do "select * from table", I see one-column coming out with JSON data.

What I really need is creating a HIVE table which could read the JSON-data in "value" column and apply schema and emit columns, so that I can create variety of tables on my RAW-data, depending on the need.

I have created hive tables on JSON file, and extracted the columns , but this extract column from parquet and apply JSON schema is tricking me

```
employee-sample.json

{"name":"Dave", "age" : 30 , "DOB":"1987-01-01"}
{"name":"Steve", "age" : 31 , "DOB":"1986-01-01"}
{"name":"Kumar", "age" : 32 , "DOB":"1985-01-01"}
```

Simple Spark code to convert JSON to parquet

```
simple-loader.java

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
            .appName(JsonToParquet.class.getName())
            .master("local[*]").getOrCreate();
    Dataset<String> eventsDataSet = sparkSession.read().textFile("D:\\dev\\employee-sample.json");
    eventsDataSet.createOrReplaceTempView("rawView");
    sparkSession.sqlContext().sql("select string(value) as value from rawView")
            .write()
            .parquet("D:\\dev\\" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    sparkSession.close();
}
```

hive table on parquet files

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE EVENTS_RAW (
VALUE STRING)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 'hdfs://XXXXXX:8020/employee/data_raw';
```

I tried by setting JSON  serde, but it works only if data is stored in JSON foram, ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.proofpoint.hive.serde.JsonSerde'

EXPECTED FORMAT

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE EVENTS_DATA (
    NAME STRING,
    AGE STRING,
    DOB STRING)
??????????????????????????????
```

Answer (score 0):

Create hive external table example:

```
 public static final String CREATE_EXTERNAL = "CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE %s" +
        " (%s) " +
        " PARTITIONED BY(%s) " +
        " STORED AS %s" +
        " LOCATION '%s'";
/**
 * Will create an external table and recover the partitions
 */
public void createExternalTable(SparkSession sparkSession, StructType schema, String tableName, SparkFormat format, List<StructField> partitions, String tablePath){
    String createQuery = createTableString(schema, tableName, format, partitions, tablePath);
    logger.info("Going to create External table with the following query:\n " + createQuery);
    sparkSession.sql(createQuery);
    logger.debug("Finish to create External table with the following query:\n " + createQuery);
    recoverPartitions(sparkSession, tableName);
}

public String createTableString(StructType schema, String tableName, SparkFormat format, List<StructField> partitions, String tablePath){
    Set<String> partitionNames = partitions.stream().map(struct -> struct.name()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    String columns = Arrays.stream(schema.fields())
            //Filter the partitions
            .filter(field -> !partitionNames.contains(field.name()))
            //
            .map(HiveTableHelper::fieldToStringBuilder)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

    String partitionsString = partitions.stream().map(HiveTableHelper::fieldToStringBuilder).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

    return String.format(CREATE_EXTERNAL, tableName, columns, partitionsString, format.name(), tablePath);
}

/**
 *
 * @param sparkSession
 * @param table
 */
public void recoverPartitions(SparkSession sparkSession, String table){
    String query = "ALTER TABLE " + table + " RECOVER PARTITIONS";
    logger.debug("Start: " + query);
    sparkSession.sql(query);
    sparkSession.catalog().refreshTable(table);
    logger.debug("Finish: " + query);
}

  public static StringBuilder fieldToStringBuilder(StructField field){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(field.name()).append( " ").append(field.dataType().simpleString());
    return sb;
}
```